# How do I remove this prop type warning with nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm getting the following warning in my console:

`Warning: Prop 'href' did not match. Server: "/register" Client: "/profile"`

The relevant code snippet is the following. If a user is logged in, show a version of the button, and if they're logged out show a different version. The server-side rendered version will always evaluate to the user being logged out. When in the browser the user is logged in, the mismatch results in this warning.

```
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HeaderContainer>
        <HeaderButton />
      </HeaderContainer>
    );
  }
}

const HeaderButton = () => {
  if (isLoggedIn()) {
    return (
      <Link href="/profile" as="/profile">
        <Button href="/profile">Profile</Button>
      </Link>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Link href="/register" as="/register">
      <Button href="/register">Register</Button>
    </Link>
  );
};
```

The code for is isLoggedIn() is:

```
export const isLoggedIn = () => {
  if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    return false;
  }

  const token = window.localStorage.getItem("bearer_token");
  if (!token) return false;
  if (!tokenIsValid(token)) return false; // inspects the JWT token
  return true;
};
```

How do I address this?

Comment: Does `isLoggedIn()` retrieve user auth info from cookies or localStorage?

Comment: Yes, from localStorage

Comment: Could you also share the `isLoggedIn()` code?

Comment: Ok cool I've added it in.

Comment: Another question: when a user logs in or logs out, does the button dynamically update, or you refresh the page completely?

Comment: For both, I have a saga function that uses `Router.push(route)`. I think this just appends to the history API and doesn't force a page refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution for this issue is to evaluate whether a user is logged in using **state hooks** in your `HeaderButton` component:

```
const HeaderButton = () => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false); // logged out by default

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoggedIn(isLoggedIn());  // calculating logged in state within effect
  });

  // and watching the state
  if (loggedIn) {
    return (
      <Link href="/profile" as="/profile">
        <Button href="/profile">Profile</Button>
      </Link>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Link href="/register" as="/register">
      <Button href="/register">Register</Button>
    </Link>
  );
};
```